# Applying function to dataframe columns spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset with considerabely large number of columns(150), I want to apply a function(UDF) on all the column expect first column, which has the id field. I was able to apply the function dynamically but now I need the final dataset with id filed back to the dataframe. The spark job will be running on cluster mode,heere is what I tried.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(("id1", "B", "c","d"), ("id2", "e", "d","k"),("id3", "e", "m","n"))).toDF("id", "dat1", "dat2","dat3")
df.show

+---+----+----+----+
| id|dat1|dat2|dat3|
+---+----+----+----+
|id1|   B|   c|   d|
|id2|   e|   d|   k|
|id3|   e|   m|   n|
+---+----+----+----+

df.select(df.columns.slice(1,df.columns.size).map(c => upper(col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show

----+----+----+
|dat1|dat2|dat3|
+----+----+----+
|   B|   C|   D|
|   E|   D|   K|
|   E|   M|   N|
+----+----+----+
```

Expected output

```
-----+----+----+
id|dat1|dat2|dat3|
-+----+----+----+
|id1|   B|   C|   D|
|id2|   E|   D|   K|
|id3|   E|   M|   N|
-+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply prepend the `id` column to the other (transformed) columns:

```
df.select(
    col("id") +: df.columns.tail.map(c => upper(col(c)).alias(c)): _*
).show
+---+----+----+----+
| id|dat1|dat2|dat3|
+---+----+----+----+
|id1|   B|   C|   D|
|id2|   E|   D|   K|
|id3|   E|   M|   N|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: simple and clean. Thanks.